# Why GKE shows backend instances not healthy?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

Following [this blog post](https://devopscube.com/setup-kubernetes-cluster-google-cloud/) I created a GKE Kubernetes cluster.

Successively I deployed Keycloak istances and if I use a `load balancer`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: load-balancer
  name: load-balancer
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    name: keycloak
  selector:
    app: keycloak
```

I can reach Keyclok.

After that following the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) I created an Ingress for accessing to Keycloak with HTTPS:

- `managed-certificate.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  domains:
    - mydomain.com
    - www.mydomain.com
```

- `keycloak-service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service
  namespace: keycloak
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

- `ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: managed-cert-ingress
  namespace: keycloak
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: keycloak
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: keycloak-service
      port:
        number: 443
```

I added liveness and readiness probes to the deployment definition of keycloak too.

But with this configuration GKE says that backend istances ar unhealthy, even if they are healthy and running:
[image]

I've read in some related questions on StackOverflow that is a issue with NAG. Should I add the firewall rules for NAG and Ingress?
If it is the point, which could be the rules?

---

EDIT: `keycloak-deployment.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-deployment
  namespace: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
        env:
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: "POSTGRES"
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: "postgres"
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: "keycloak"
        - name: DB_USER
          value: "keycloak"
        - name: DB_SCHEMA
          value: "public"
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: "password"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "password"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_STATISTICS
          value: all
        - name: JDBC_PARAMS
          value: "useSSL=false"
        - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
          value: "JDBC_PING"
        - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES
          value: datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,info_writer_sleep_time=500,initialize_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING ( own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, created timestamp default current_timestamp, ping_data BYTEA, constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name))"
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
        startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 9990
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 9990
          initialDelaySeconds: 0
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 9990
          successThreshold: 3
```

Comment: How does your keycloak deployment spec looks like, can you post it in the question?

Comment: I've posted keycloak deployment in the question

Comment: You ran with `replicas: 2` but your spec is a standalone keycloak. It seems you want to run keycloak with SSL but you have not specified the cert/key file? There are several other issues... Suggest you use [Bitnami Keycloak chart](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/integrate-keycloak-authentication-kubernetes) and [guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/apps/keycloak/get-started/expose-service/) using ingress for keycloak will be a lot easier.

Comment: Whit Bitnami Keycloak chart can I use Google managed certificates for the Ingress with `ingress.annotations` right?